# How can i select the last worksheet using With

Tags: vba, excel

My code looks something like this:

```
Sub My Button1()
    With Worksheets("6th Oct")
        With .Range(.Cells(3, "Q"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
             .Formula = "=IF(OR(J3=""Pending"",J3=""Assigned""),""Pending"",IF(AND(J3=""Closed"",E3=M3),""Passed"",""Failed""))"
        End With
    End With
    Range("Q2").Value = "Test"
End Sub
```

As the worksheet name is always different, I want to remove the specific name i.e. "6th Oct" and point to the last worksheet here. Can anyone please help me on how to do that?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "the last worksheet here"?  The last one in tab order (i.e. `Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)`)?  Or the last one created?  Or the one with a name that looks like it might be the latest date? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily select the last Worksheet in a Workbook by using

```
Workbooks("Name of your Workbook").Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

For Example

```
With Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    'Do whatever you want
End With
```

---

### How to use it in your code

I believe what you're trying to do in your code would be done like this

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    'Do whatever you want
End With
```

*Thanks to @YowE3K and @ChrisNeilsen for the contribution in the comments*

Comment: You should also qualify `Worksheets.Count`with the required workbook, otherwise you will get the count of worksheets in the active workbook

Answer (score 0):

To access the last sheet of the workbook, use of this command:

```
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Select
```

try this:

```
Dim Current As Worksheet

' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each Current In Worksheets
    If Current.Name = "6th Oct" Then Current.Delete
Next

With Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    With .Range(.Cells(3, "Q"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
        .Formula = "=IF(OR(J3=""Pending"",J3=""Assigned""),""Pending"",IF(AND(J3=""Closed"",E3=M3),""Passed"",""Failed""))"
    End With
End With
Range("Q2").Value = "Test"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks it was just a stupid error, using with it already selects the sheet and no need to use the Select. Thanks man